# How can I find the Fourier series expansion of this (discontinuous) function?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series

Consider the following function
$$
f(x) = \cases{0 \hspace{10mm} - \pi < x < 0 \\ 1 \hspace{16mm} 0 < x < \pi}
$$

I wish to find the Fourier series expansion of this function. To do this, I know that a periodic function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $(-L, L)$ has the Fourier expansion
$$
F(x) = \frac{a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( a_n Cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) + b_n Sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \right)
$$

where the coefficients $a_n , b_n$ are given by
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) Cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx
$$
and
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) Sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx
$$

So for our function, the fourier coefficients would be
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) Cos \left( nx \right) dx
$$
and
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) Sin \left( nx \right) dx
$$

But since our function is undefined at $x=-\pi$ and $x=\pi$ we cannot say what these integrals are?

Comment: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos(nx)\, dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(nx)\, dx$

Comment: Complete your function over a set of measure $0$ to make it a traditional step function (or square wave), which has a very simple Fourier representation.

Comment: What about vales beyond $-\pi \ldots \pi$ ?

Comment: When you have a function that is continuous on $(a,b)$ but not defined at $a, b$ it is safe to substitute the left hand limits and right and limits in the evaluation of $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx.$  The Fourrier series will converge on the midpoint between those limits at the discontinues.

Comment: @Harry49 Thanks. I've noticed that this is equal to 0, and so is the integral for the coefficient of $b_n$. This would mean that our Fourier expansion of the function would be $F(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}$. This surely cannot be correct?

Comment: The $b_n$ coefficients are nonzero for odd integers $n$.